# Replacing special char in all table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some text values in text columns that I would like to change quickly.

The text value in question is `%S`.

An example for such a text in text column is

```
You're just downloading %S.
```

or

```
%S has successfully been updated.
```

I would like to change `%S` so that the 2 fields would for example read

```
You're just downloading MySuperApp.
```

and

```
MySuperApp has successfully been updated.
```

The character % itself is an operator in an SQLite search, and I don't know how I could wrap it to be some text value.

Also, I don't know the required SQL command to change only a part of a text in a single SQLite statement.
So far, I've only changed entire field texts, not certain parts of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The character % itself is an operator in an SQLite search, and I don't know how I could wrap it to be some text value.

You could use `REPLACE` function(there is no need for wrapping it):

```
WITH cte(t) AS (
   VALUES ('You''re just downloading %S.'),
   ('%S has successfully been updated.')
)
SELECT t, REPLACE(t, '%S', 'MyUserApp') AS replaced
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=115989f6088182616a244eabbc106347)**

Or if you need `UPDATE` table:

```
UPDATE tab_name
SET col_name = REPLACE(col_name, '%S', 'specific value')
WHERE col_name LIKE '%^%S%' ESCAPE '^';  -- here you have to escape it
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=678d7da192d26e0c03dbfb2529ab671b)**